# Связать ObservableCollection данные с другой коллекцией

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется класс наследованный от INotifyPropertyChanged. И List не изменяемый забитый экземплярами этого класса в количестве 128 штук (кол-во нот). Также имеется UniformGrid во вьюхе. Вопрос как мне сделать ItemsSource таким образом, когда изменение свойства одного объекта, меняет свойства нескольких на гриде.
Заполнение ObservableCollection нужно как то сделать в виде ссылок на объект из List-а, а не копии их.
Примерно хочу получить такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну если у вас действительно объекты, то все должно работать из коробки. Если в список один и тот же объект добавлен несколько раз, то при изменении свойств этого объекта обновятся все items вашего ItemsControl, привязанные к этому объекту

Comment: Проведите пример кода и напишите что конкретно не работает

Comment: Блин, точно ссылками передаётся. Извиняюсь за свою тупость, вопрос закрыт.